# Copy the link breed variable in the patch below

Tags: netlogo

I have a network of nodes and links. This figure

[image]

is a capture of the world. The graph represents streets of a city. I have imported a shapefile with the gis extension. The gray lines are links, black dots are nodes and red dots represent people. The people move heading to the next node. In a street corner, the red dot chooses next street by examining the variable `popularity` owned by the link.

The links breed has a variable, `popularity`, whose value I would like to copy in the patches that are below.

If I try, for example, something like this to access patches under links will produce an error

```
ask links [show [(list pxcor pycor)] of patch-here]
```

Another approach can be to access links variable popularity from patches, but I do not know how to do it.

The reason why I want this is because I want to write in a file a matrix of popularity values and its position in the matrix should correspond with the position of the link in the world. Thus, the patches below the links would give me the matrix form. I have a procedure that for each patch writes the value of the patch in a file. However, I do not know how to pass the `popularity`value from the link to the patch below it.

Is there any way to copy a link owned variable to its patch?

Regards

Comment: A link connects 2 turtles. Multiple links can run over any patch, and each link runs over many patches. Links move as turtles move. This means there is no actual connection between links and patches. Maybe you could draw a network and the matrix that you expect to help us understand what you want?

Comment: @JenB thanks for the comment. I have uploaded a screenshot of the scenario. From your comment, it seems hard to make what I need. Maybe there is another way to copy the links variable in the patch.

Comment: @JenB For example, could I run a procedure to ask both end nodes of a link to copy the `popularity`of a shared link in the patches that are in the line between them?. Some nodes are close so that a single patch will have more than one node, in that case, I would take the maximum value of the `popularity`.

Comment: thanks for the image, this is much clearer - your turtle positions and links are fixed. Presumably, popularity is something like traffic density. Short answer is that it is possible to do what you want, not hard but a little fiddly. The method is something like 'ask each link, get the pair of turtles at each end, find their location, and assign the popularity value to all patches between the locations', taking the maximum if necessary. If nobody answers, I will write something tomorrow.

Comment: @JenB I have unsucceeded trying to find the set of patches between two nodes. I would appreciate your help very much.

Comment: I've written something. It would have been better for you to make an attempt based on my description of the procedure, and then come to StackOverflow when you got stuck. However, this was particularly awkward to write and therefore hard for a novice. In the future, please make an attempt to write the code yourself and show us what you have written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If someone has a better way of doing this (or can simplify my code), feel free. Here is a complete working example. Copy it into an empty NetLogo model and run it to see it work.

The `setup` procedure just creates some nodes and links with appropriate test values and then calls the transfer-link-values procedure, which does what I think you want. The `setup` procedure then puts the values into the patch labels to display them and see the results.

The way the transfer-link-values procedure works is to create a turtle at one end of the link, and that turtle moves toward the other end of the link transferring the value as it goes. When it gets to the other end, the turtle dies.

```
patches-own [patch-popularity]
links-own [link-popularity]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 10 [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
  while [ any? turtles with [not any? my-links] ]
  [ let to-pair turtles with [not any? my-links]
    let thisNode one-of to-pair
    ask thisNode
    [ create-link-with one-of other to-pair
      [ set link-popularity 5 + random 5 ]
    ]
  ]

  transfer-link-values
  ask patches [ if patch-popularity != 0 [set plabel patch-popularity ] ]
end

to transfer-link-values
  ask links
  [ let start-node one-of both-ends
    let this-link self
    let end-node nobody
    ask start-node [ set end-node [other-end] of this-link ]
    let transfer-value link-popularity
    ask start-node
    [ hatch 1
      [ face end-node
        if transfer-value > patch-popularity
          [ ask patch-here [ set patch-popularity transfer-value ] ]
        while [ not member? end-node turtles-here ]
        [ forward 1
          if transfer-value > patch-popularity
            [ ask patch-here [ set patch-popularity transfer-value ] ]
        ]
        if transfer-value > patch-popularity
            [ ask patch-here [ set patch-popularity transfer-value ] ]
        die
      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: The code is awesome. Thank you very much. I have reduced the hatched turtle forwarding distance in the while loop.

Comment: yes, a smaller `forward` would be required if there were lots of diagonal roads since they might cut off a corner.

Answer (score 1):

Quite late to the party but I think this is useful for other people with a similar problem.

I created the `patches-under-links` reporter which returns all the patches over which a link crosses. It works by first calculating the linear equation that defines the link, then checking where this linear equation crosses any of the borders between patches, and finally combining the patches on each side of these border intersections into a patch-set.

I included a small example where I use it to count how many links cross over each patch

It does not yet work with world wrapping.

```
 patches-own [links-above]


 to setup
  
  ca
  resize-world -20 20 -20 20
  ask patches [set links-above 0]
  crt 50 [set size 0.1 setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
  ask turtles [create-links-with n-of 3 other turtles [set color red ]]
  ask links [ask patches-under-link [set links-above links-above + 1]]
  ask patches [set pcolor scale-color grey links-above 0 max [links-above] of patches ]
  
end


to-report patches-under-link
  ;A link-reporter
  
  let lcors [list xcor ycor] of both-ends
  let lxcor1 item 0 item 0 lcors
  let lycor1 item 1 item 0 lcors
  let lxcor2 item 0 item 1 lcors
  let lycor2 item 1 item 1 lcors
  
  
  let all-patches (patch-set)
  
  ifelse lxcor1 = lxcor2 [ ;this specific case is separate since it would result in a 0 in the nominator for the slope calculation
    
    set all-patches patches with [pxcor = round lxcor1 and pycor <= max list round lycor1 round lycor2 and pycor >= min list round lycor1 round lycor2]
    
  ][
    
    let xdif lxcor2 - lxcor1
    let ydif lycor2 - lycor1
    
    let lslope ydif / xdif ; the slope of the linear equation: a
    let lintercept lycor1 - lslope * lxcor1 ; the intercept of the linear equation: b
    let fx [ x -> lslope * x + lintercept] ; linear equation of the link: y = ax + b
    let fy [ y -> (y - lintercept) / lslope] ; linear equation of the link: x = (y - b) / a
    
    let x-intercepts ifelse-value lxcor1 < lxcor2 [(range (round lxcor1 + 0.5) (round lxcor2 + 0.5))] [(range (round lxcor2 + 0.5) (round lxcor1 + 0.5) )]
    let y-intercepts ifelse-value lycor1 < lycor2 [(range (round lycor1 + 0.5) (round lycor2 + 0.5))] [(range (round lycor2 + 0.5) (round lycor1 + 0.5) )]
    
    let x-patches patch-set map [x ->
      (patch-set patch x (runresult fx x) patch (x - 0.0000001) (runresult fx (x - 0.0000001)))
    ] x-intercepts
    
    let y-patches patch-set map [y ->
      (patch-set patch (runresult fy y) y patch (runresult fy (y - 0.0000001))  (y - 0.0000001))
    ] y-intercepts
    
    set all-patches (patch-set x-patches y-patches)
  ]
  
  report all-patches

end
```

Comment: This could also be converted into a more general way of looking up all patches between two points, or all patches in from of a turtle